# ¿Uso incorrecto de la preposición "en"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

Me parece que en el titular de este artículo (*[El inusual fenómeno meteorológico que puede llegar este fin de semana en Asturias](https://www.lavozdeasturias.es/noticia/asturias/2022/05/20/inusual-fenomeno-meteorologico-puede-llegar-fin-semana-asturias/00031653037941663928877.htm)*) se utiliza mal una preposición, pero querría consultar si soy yo quien se equivoca.

¿No debería ser *El inusual fenómeno meteorológico que puede llegar este fin de semana **a** Asturias*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cuestión**: "*El inusual fenómeno meteorológico que puede llegar este fin de semana en Asturias*"

Tal como se expresa la noticia, donde se emplea un verbo de probabilidad y el verbo "llegar", la utilización que se hace de la preposición "en" es errónea.

El informador ha confundido la preposición "en", considerando la noticia desde el lugar donde ocasionalmente esta puede acabar produciéndose, es decir, "en Asturias", equivocando este sentido de "lugar", "en", con el valor de destino que en este caso tiene la preposición "a".

- La preposición "a" se utiliza para indicar el destino. "Llegar a". "El inusual fenómeno meteorológico puede llegar a Asturias este fin de semana"
- La preposición "en" se utiliza para indicar situación, instrumento, medio o estado de algo, una ubicación que expresa temporalidad, que puede ser estática o permanente. (Llego en cinco minutos, llego en autobús, llega en mal estado).

Otras preposiciones.

- La preposición "hasta" puede expresar el término o un límite temporal (este fin de semana), el espacio o la cantidad. Cuando "hasta" va seguido de un verbo, delimita el momento en que acabaría la acción.  "...puede llegar este fin de semana hasta Asturias".
- Preposición "hacia", indica dirección.

Así pues, lo correcto sería:

"*El inusual fenómeno meteorológico que puede llegar este fin de semana a Asturias*"

Por tanto, estás en lo cierto y no te equivocas.